# Is there a way to select hardcoded values under the same column name

Tags: oracle

I have 3 values 'ABC', 'DEF', and 'GHI' and I need to select them as a single column from the table so that output is:

```
Column1
________
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT 'ABC' AS column1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI' FROM DUAL;
```

Or, use a collection:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS column1
FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'));
```

Which both output:

> | COLUMN1 |
> | --- |
> | ABC |
> | DEF |
> | GHI |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30bdb225e1567c4ebac3a92ae1aff512)*